# Track Modules that `use` another module

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to keep track of all modules that `use` another module at compile-time and get a list of all these module at runtime:

```
defmodule BaseModule do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      # common behaviour
    end
  end
end


defmodule A do
  use BaseModule
end

defmodule B do
  use BaseModule
end

defmodule C do
  use BaseModule
end
```

And get them at runtime by calling something like this:

```
BaseModule.children()
#=> [A, B, C]
```

---

I have been trying to find a way to accomplish this but still have absolutely no idea on how to do it. Going through [this thread on the elixir-lang mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/PhnZkaTSpx4), [@josevalim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jos%C3%A9-valim) recommends using `Protocols` to do this. But after struggling this for about an hour, I can't get it to work with Protocols either.

I've also been looking in to the `Registry` module to see if I can accomplish this using that, but it looks like it's designed to work with processes mainly.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your use Macro include a behaviour into the target module. There will need to be some effect to the target module because a `__using__` macro could return no effect and the it would be impossible to detect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your base module uses a behaviour then the following solution is possible.

```
defmodule BaseModule do
  @callback foo() :: any()

  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      # Fairly standard to use a behaviour and gives us something to detect later.
      @behaviour unquote(__MODULE__)

      # Any other setup required
    end
  end

  def children() do
    (for {module, _} <- :code.all_loaded(), do: module)
    |> Enum.filter(&is_child?/1)
  end

  def is_child?(module) do
    module.module_info[:attributes]
    |> Keyword.get(:behaviour, [])
    |> Enum.member?(__MODULE__)
  end
end

defmodule A do
  use BaseModule
end

BaseModule.children()
#=> [A]
```

Comment: Yes, this is good! But my only problem with this is that `:code.all_loaded()` doesn't always list all modules (because the VM lazy loads them), I'm hoping there's something else that always gives the same result.

Comment: Fair enough, and it's not something I had thought about. But you won't be able to reach out to find modules not loaded. In essence they won't have 'used' BaseModule because their use line won't have been called.

Comment: True true, and this is still a really good solution. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Note that `:behaviour` might exist multiple times in the module_info attributes list (in case of implementing multiple behaviours), `Keyword.get_values/2` helps there.